# HEVC VIdeo Extensions keep taking memory until UWP app crashes

Tags: windows, memory-management, uwp, ms-media-foundation, hevc

I am using [HEVC Video Extensions](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/hevc-video-extensions/9nmzlz57r3t7?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) in order to decode video on my UWP video app. The problem is that the HEVC app takes so much memory during playback that I am unable to play large 4k files without crashing.

If I use the HEVC hardware only I am able to have better use of memory but limited in 4k on it.

I have tried HEVC Extension and tried to see if there is garbage cleanup I can do but have not been successful in lowering the memory

Just setting my video like this:

```
MediaSource ams_02 = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(fileHere_02);
elementToSet.Source = ams_02;
```

Memory Should be handled better in order to create possible playback on a 4k,2+ hour movie without running out of memory.

Thank you

Comment: Is there an SDK for the HEVC Video Extensions?  Can you post a link to that?

Comment: Also can you post some more of your code attempts?

Comment: HEVC Video Extensions is a Media Foundation software version of [H.265/HEVC Decoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/h-265---hevc-video-decoder). So yes, it could be greedy for memory.

Comment: True, but it just takes memory constantly until crashes, for example counts up to 4 gigs for the decoder

Comment: Im not using sdk, just using the hevc video extension app

Comment: If it has a symptom of a memory leak, you should probably report this via MS Feedback Hub app.

Comment: Can you tell us the version about the system and plugin? And what's the content of source and where is the source being hosted?

Comment: Sure, so system version is the 1.0.22763.0 of the HEVC Video Extensions
I am running 1903 version of windows, latest updates


I am running a i3 Processor

I am testing on 4k HEVC Tears of Steel.
The source is being hosted locally in a Documents Folder.

Comment: I see the a large memory growth in tears of Steele like 1,000 mb in first few mins. The other  source is 3 hour 4K movie that is hevc encoded, that one crashes the and get a out of memory error when get like 3,000ish mb

Comment: So I think the hevc encoder is working but playready crashes by not freeing up memory when it reaches full memory like it should

Comment: @marinamovies32 are you still seeing this issue? If so, does this issue only occur with PR or does it also occur with unencrypted content? I'm tracking something similar but want to confirm your scenario.

Comment: So the memory gets very very high with clear hevc data and then once reaches maximum memory frees up a little at a time but still very high memory usage. When PR is used then the foundation pipeline has a high memory footprint, except when it reaches maximum memory doesn’t free it and crashes the program. For now using H264 as memory is kept sub 500 mb for the entire time for smooth playback