# I would like to switch the codec, or use a installed codec for UWP that can use playready

Tags: video, uwp, codec

I would like to use a installed HEVC decoder for my UWP, but it also needs to use playready as well. Reason is the current software solution for HEVC is not working as I would like from Microsoft. Is there a solution to playing a different codec? Thank you!

Tried HEVC Decoder from Microsoft but right now takes up to much memory
Tried FFMPEG but cant do playready in UWP

Would like to play a HEVC playready encoded file in UWP with a differently installed HEVC codec.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of DRM is to decode the video content in secure protected environment where neither encoded content restored from encryption nor its decoded derivative are accessible to external code. It is supposed that this video is securely played only and cannot be copied directly or via re-encoding. PlayReady DRM implementation makes it sure by using an authorized codec (I skip unnecessary detail here) and so you must be using Microsoft decoder in the case of PlayReady DRM enabled playback.

Even if you have [intermittent problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58600214/hevc-video-extensions-keep-taking-memory-until-uwp-app-crashes) with Microsoft decoder implementation, your only solution to this problem is to report issues to Microsoft and expect them to fix codec from their end.